# Adding Sequential numbers in woocommerce for each order separated by product

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a website selling digital postbox numbers, currently only one city so I used custom order numbers plugin to change the order numbers automaticallly to sequential numbers to match the postbox numbers I can provide.

Now I'm adding 2 more cities, and I want to create a separate numbering system for them as each city's postboxes starts with the number 1200, so I will not be able to provide 2 postboxes with number 1200 for example for 2 cities if I'm using custom order numbers.

is there a solution for this?

my only idea is to create subdomains for each city with different WP installation

so simply it should be

```
Product A = Numbers start from 1200, +1 added for each sale
Product B = numbers start from 1200, +1 added for each sale
Product C = numbers start from 1200, +1 added for each sale
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into a prefix or suffix for your order ids which will denote which city its been purchased for

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2);

    function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
        $prefix = '#CITY-';
        // you will need to get your city as a variable to pass in to priffix 
        $suffix = '-' . date(Y); 
        // You can use either one of $order->id (or) $order_id
        // Both will work
        return $prefix . $order->id . $suffix;
    }
```